# How to parse CSV which contains \n in data using Apache Spark?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I have some CSV files which have `\n` character in the data itself. I am trying to read these files in `Apache Spark 2.2` but Spark is not able to read the data properly.

Sample data is like below:

```
column1,column2,column3,column4,...,column300\n
column1,column2,"""this column has \n new line char and comma,",column4,...,column300\n
column1,column2,column3,column4,...,column300\n
```

As shown above all rows end with `\n` character and not with `\r\n`.

Second row

- has a column which has both `\n` and comma as part of data itself
- value of column begins with 3 double quotes and ends with one double quote
- **"""this column has \n new line char and comma,"**

My code to read this CSV is pretty simple and standard.

```
val filePath = "ap-data/lines.csv"
val csv = spark.read.format("csv").option("inferSchema", "true").load(filePath)
```

I have tried many options like `option("escape","\n")` or `.option("mode", "FAILFAST")` but none of the options have worked.

Spark converts these 3 rows to 4 rows as shown below:

```
row 1 => column1,column2,column3,column4,...,column300\n
row 2 => column1,column2,"""this column has 
row 3 => new line char and comma,",column4,...,column300\n
row 4 => column1,column2,column3,column4,...,column300\n
```

Actual data has millions of rows and all the columns which have `\n` in them follow the same format, i.e. columns begin with 3 double quotes and end with one double quote.

How can I parse this type of data correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I have come to conclusion that as of now Spark does not handle this type of CSV files. (I'm not blaming Spark, input files which we are receiving have invalid values in it).

So I wrote my own custom record reader and it works like a charm.

I took help of [this blog](https://www.ae.be/blog-en/ingesting-data-spark-using-custom-hadoop-fileinputformat/) to write custom record reader.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks perfect.

The only defect I see is

> > value of column begins with 3 double quotes and ends with one double quote

So you would need to **replace the 3 double quotes to 1 double quote**

I would suggest you to create temporary file and use your code as

```
val filePath = "ap-data/lines.csv"
val tempFilePath = "ap-data/tempLines.csv"
val textrdd = sc.textFile(filePath).map(line => line.replace("\"\"\"", "\"")).saveAsTextFile(tempFilePath)
val csv = spark.read.format("csv").option("inferSchema", "true").load(tempFilePath)
```

and you should be fine

Comment: That seems like a great idea. Perhaps I could skip saving that textrdd and use it as it is?

Comment: your intention is good but you won't be able benefit from inbuilt sqlcontext apis.

Comment: ah ok. Thanks a lot, will try it out and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities. From the results that I see, row 1, row 2 and so on, for row 2 there is no new line character. So what you could possibly do is that you can go over the rows once again and for those rows where there is no new line character, concatenate it with the next row and keep doing this until you hit a new line character!

If using Shapeless is an option, have a look here for how you could box your CSV line into a case class. This way, you can get rid of the problem you have encountered!

https://github.com/joesan/csv-parser/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/inland24/csvparser/CSVParser.scala

Answer (score 1):

if your spark version is 3, then try following scripts：
pyspark ↓

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("multiline",True).option("delimiter",",").option("header",True).load(DATA_PATH)
```